# State of the art low memory arbitrary-domain PRP?

Tags: format-preserving, pseudo-random-permutation

I am wondering what the state of the art is on low memory arbitrary-domain PRPs.

That is, I'm looking for an algorithm that implements bijective function $PRP : \mathbb{Z}_n \times \{0, 1\}^b \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$, where $b$ is an acceptable security level (say, 256 bit).

Such a function is trivial to construct by using a Fisher-Yates shuffle with an appropriate source of pseudo-randomness on a full array of size $n$. However, I'm looking for an algorithm that does not use $O(n)$ memory, but rather on the order of $O(\log n)$.

Even more ideally, I'm looking for an algorithm with a flexible key schedule, such that no precomputation for a certain key is needed. Does this exist, or is it impossible?

Comment: The problem seems to be studied, and solved, by [format-preserving encryption](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format-preserving). We have tag for that.

Comment: @fgrieu Added the tag.

Comment: Is there even a PRF with such low space requirements? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer As an example, the core function used in Blake2 is a PRP on domain $\{0, 1\}^{512} $ that uses $2 \cdot 512$ bits of memory.

Comment: Does it seem to have a security level significantly above 512 bits? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer The security level is distinct from the block (domain) size. E.g. AES has a block size of 128, but provided security levels of 128, 192 and 256 bits (although the latter two have later found attacks reducing their security, this is besides the point).

Comment: Oohh, is your space requirement for when log(n) is not significantly less than b? ​ (I was assuming the other way around.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I don't fully understand your question. $b$ is not really relevant to the question, and you can assume it's some fixed value, e.g. 128 or 256. Unless my math fails me the number of possible permutations of $n$ elements is $n!$, and $35! > 2^{128}$, so a too small domain will only be an issue in the smallest possible cases.

Comment: If we take [b being fixed] completely seriously, then O(1) memory suffices - If ​ 2^(2^b) < n ​ then use the identity function on Zn, else use any PRP on Zn. ​ ​ ​ To avoid that, one must assume some relation between n and b. ​ ​ ​ I had initially been assuming log(n) was significantly less than b (making things more difficult), but it now seems like your interested in when log(n) is significantly greater than b. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I am interested in your claimed algorithm that has a fixed security level of $2^{128}$ (AKA $b = 128$) which gives a PRP on an arbitrary domain of size $n$ (where $n \geq 35$) in $O(1)$ memory.

Comment: If ​ 2^(2^128) < n ​ then encryption just outputs the plaintext and decryption just outputs the ciphertext. ​ ​ ​ If ​ n ≤ 2^(2^128) ​ then [sometimes-recurse shuffle](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/sr.html) with 128 bits of security. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I think I misunderstood sometimes-recurse shuffle then. Either way, feel free to post your thoughts as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's the algorithm for "a fixed security level of 2<sup>128</sup>":

If ​ n ≤ 2^(2^128) ​ then [sometimes-recurse shuffle](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/sr.html) with 128 bits of security.

If ​ 2^(2^128) < n ​ then encryption just outputs the

plaintext and decryption just outputs the ciphertext.

The identity function can trivially be computed in O(1) space, so that algorithm

also uses only O(1) space. ​ (That's why, for true asymptotic analysis, one must

usually  assume some relation between n and the security parameter.)